# Android -- OnCreateView called twice - each time the orientation changes and loses the field values

Tags: java, android

I know that this is a talked about topic, but nothing recently.   I followed all the methods suggested to NOT create twice, but it still does and because of this I lose the information.   Any ideas on how to fix?   Thanks in advance for the help!

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base_info, container, false);
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
    mShantiName = (EditText) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.baseInfoShantiName);
    mEmail = (EditText) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.baseInfoEmail);
    mPassword = (EditText) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.baseInfoPassword);
    mFirstName = (EditText) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.baseInfoFirstName);
    mLastName = (EditText) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.baseInfoLastName);
    mPhone = (EditText) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.baseInfoPhone);
    mPhonePerfixMS = (MultiSpinner) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.baseInfoPhonePrefix);
    mShantiName.setText("fh");
    mEmail.setText("d@f.com");
    mPassword.setText("33ddSS..");
    mFirstName.setText("gh");
    mLastName.setText("rf");
    mPhone.setText("5551212");

    a++;
    DeviceDisplayLanguage = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
    if (DeviceDisplayLanguage.equals(getActivity().getString(R.string.DeviceDisplayGerman)))
        mPassword.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
    if (Common.user != null && ((Common.user.getNvGoogleUserId() != null && !Common.user.getNvGoogleUserId().equals("")) || (Common.user.getNvFacebookUserId() != null && !Common.user.getNvFacebookUserId().equals("")))) {
        isLoginWith = true;
        mPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        init();
    } else {
        isLoginWith = false;
        mPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        i++;
        mShantiName.setText(savedInstanceState.get("Name").toString());
        mEmail.setText(savedInstanceState.get("Email").toString());
        mPassword.setText(savedInstanceState.get("Password").toString());
        mFirstName.setText(savedInstanceState.get("FirstName").toString());
        mLastName.setText(savedInstanceState.get("LastName").toString());
        mPhone.setText(savedInstanceState.get("Phone").toString());
    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "i=" + i + "j=" + j + "a=" + a,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mPhonePerfix = (CountryToPhonePrefix.prefixFor(tMgr.getNetworkCountryIso().toUpperCase()));
    initializer = new CustomViewsInitializer(getActivity());
    if (((MultiSpinner) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.baseInfoPhonePrefix)).getChooseValues().size() > 0)
        selected = ((MultiSpinner) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.baseInfoPhonePrefix)).getChooseValues().get(0);

    initializer.setSpinner(mPhonePerfixMS, CodeValue.countries, getString(R.string.signUpPhonePrefix), selected);


   // InitValidation();
    mRootView.findViewById(R.id.baseInfoCreateUserBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
    mShantiName.requestFocus();
    return mRootView;
}
```

Comment: We tried the saved and restore method but I suspect something is missing....

Answer (score 0):

In orientation Change you need to save your data in onSaveInstanceState method I think you missed that method that's why you loses the field values.

```
//Here you Save your data
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("Name", mShantiName.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("Email", mEmail.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("Password", mPassword.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("FirstName", mFirstName.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("LastName", mLastName.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("Phone", mPhone.getText().toString());


    }
```

Example :

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment {


        private EditText title;
        private Button go_next;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true); //Will ignore onDestroy Method (Nested Fragments no need this if parent have it)
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            onRestoreInstanceStae(savedInstanceState);
            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }


        //Here you can restore saved data in onSaveInstanceState Bundle
        private void onRestoreInstanceStae(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                String SomeText = savedInstanceState.getString("title");            
            }
        }

        //Here you Save your data
        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putString("title", "Some Text");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you but it still is causing a problem.  In a trace we are seeing that we save the instance and we put the instance but where is the connection between to the saved instance and the DISPLAY of the information in the fields of the window....

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        if (mSpinnerstate != null)
            outState.putInt("category", mSpinnerstate.getSelection());
        // do this for each or your Spinner
        // You might consider using Bundle.putStringArray() instead
    }
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          if (savedInstanceState != null)
                        mSpinnerstate.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("category", 0));
}
```